# OL: static image (using proj4 defs) overlay with LONLAT bounds - result wrongly positioned (is shifted)

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-5

I have an image from weathermodel output. It's a transparent (static) image that I need to overlay on an (openlayer) map. The image itself is based on a polair stereographic projection (EPSG: 32661). I use proj4.defs for 32661. The imgExtent I got from the person who made the png's (so I presume there is nothing wrong with those bounds).

The static IMG:

```
var imgExtent = [0,49,10,55]; // LONLAT bounds


IMGlyr = new ol.layer.Image({
    name: 'myIMG',
    source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
        url: 'http://www.kambeel.nl/data/img_orig.png',
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        imageExtent: ol.extent.applyTransform(imgExtent, ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:32661"))
    })
});
```

However when I overlay the image the result is a shifted image.......what am I overseeing?? Don't know anymore.....

The result (shifted image): http://www.kambeel.nl/data/result.png

Answer (score 0):

This would work of the image exactly fitted the coordinates.  However it has a few pixels transparent margin on each edge which needs to be removed to work correctly.

```
source: new ol.source.ImageStatic({
    url: 'http://www.kambeel.nl/data/img_orig.png',
    projection: "EPSG:32661",
    imageExtent: ol.extent.boundingExtent([ ol.proj.transform([0,49], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:32661"),
                                            ol.proj.transform([10,55], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:32661") ])
})
```

Comment: Looks like the corners might not be quite right as well: [image cropped to box on image](http://www.geocodezip.com/OL_5.3.0_simple_ImageLayer.html)

Comment: Yes, the Greenwich meridian on the graticule isn't vertically aligned as it should be for EPSG:32661.  1 degree east looks close to vertical and changing `+lon_0=0` to `+lon_0=1` in the proj4 def makes the coastlines align better, but Luxembourg is still offset.

Comment: OK.....thx. I now know that I was on the right track. Asked the person whom this image is from if the used projection might e.g. be rotated a little in order to center it over the NL. Will let you know if I solved my problem!